# Understanding "upright threat displays"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Bipedalism would have allowed early hominids to see over tall grasses,
>   helping them to locate food and to detect and avoid predators.
>   However, substantial advantages upon early hominids who never left the
>   forest-in gathering food found within standing reach of the forest
>   floor, for example- debate continues concerning its origins. **It may
>   even have evolved, like the upright threat displays of many large
>   apes, because it bettered an individual's odds of finding a mate.**

I cannot understand the last sentence, especially because of the part "like the upright threat displays of many large apes". Can someone explain what this sentence means?

I am having trouble with "upright threat displays". Does this mean "any threats that are made because of upright posture of large apes"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "[threat display](http://www.biology-online.org/dictionary/Threat_Display)" is a behavior intended to intimidate other creatures and to signal that an attack is imminent. The word "[upright](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/upright)" in this context means "*erect in posture or carriage*". We know that we should choose that definition because the paragraph is talking about bipedalism. We use "to walk upright" to describe walking on two feet (instead of four).

If you know about "to walk upright", then it makes sense that "upright threat displays" means threat displays performed while standing erect.